# How can I use op-amps to compare two varying signals, and send out a signal if they deviate?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, potentiometer

I am going to make a circuit (APPS, Accelerator Pedal Position Sensor Circuit) that sends out a signal if the input signals deviate more than 10%. It's one inverted signal (10V-0V) and one non-inverted signal (0V-10V). The signals come from two potentiometers, which are connected to a gas pedal. One pot which is flipped, which gives an inverted signal and one that isn't. I'm going to put a physical restriction on the signals, so they go from 10V-5V and 0V-5V.
So my question now, is how can I detect if they deviate more than 10% from each other, and make the circuit send a signal somewhere else if this happens? My current circuit is made with two Unity Gain Buffers, so the pots doesn't interfere with the gain of the op amp (differential amplifier) which amplifies the difference, which sends this signal to a comparator. It may be that I have wrong numbers as well, so please post suggestions for that as well. If desired, I can join a voice call through medias, like discord, provide further rules for clarification and show my proposal for the circuit in a simulator.

The right part is logic circuits for detecting if the signal is too high or too low individually. First of all, the two comparators in the top right checks if the signal is too low. The top one checks if the first signal (0V-5V) is too low. The lower comparator checks if the second signal (inverted, 10V-5V) is too low. The two comparators in the bottom check if they are too high. Top checks first signal, lower checks second signal. The AND gate sends the signal if all is ok, and the OR gate shuts the system down. The left part of the circuit is the deviation detector, which I need help with.
[Current circuit draft](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKAHcQAWPcMFEPFWb9ILAIYChKHmGL8%20PGUiZIw8eCBTRuGTrrw4MCPHmbZN2g3oR8EKHXuTr24OeGkhsadz1FhK7nDgnJzg2G5gIVDUSAgsnJAQXkJRnF7BoRB4ADoAzv55Knlq6pB5MAjlsCg23KTYCNh4xJzGhJX5pVB5aMWlXWDl8YkCYISe3nI8yeACxR1FnaV5HZzQZJykW9tbferdub1L-UGDuaIJWWMgDNwgUzd3WfOFBcfwK9BnHSUaZYf-X4ncBDMC6G52HiYfi3YjjGYQIFQWCQJAAJTouQAlrkAC5iAB2AGM6CwAOYQjzYbDjBiQzx2aIXEamWlg8YPJgYcbPfILN5AuDlPJrDY7cXEPZ-HqAk4aM7Mq7jTiEUIPFWZOZ814-fp9T5nQUHI6CgZDNEQ7m8GGqoR8JlcIRUZ3IuIAJ0pUPwns0GBETjgLgYaGmkFCwe9Y2dQZD4EIVCY9qjUBj3tw4c28LDKYS5ljsep42h0RQAH1VaXIKXOGoyzBIOFIIQapWUXAyO1mwhK6Wy2XsOIbtIeKqbrJ%20KPiOBlP4AxpRVtKJRIhseKpSoPE-IrUweVap7OVHOgqLdMRKDUw2LQqfNhLtseXIIMlwZFFRBwnqkZFaP2Ok24W6aPYKYcEBKAgbuwGhH%20UEQeG1zsimHrPpEoTPvB0RAuSkjQdaeHRhwnJIaQMJIX%20nJPGGCZ3BRVLeGoCQTIR9weBqyAIMqo6iB6xH7h4wacVh8AsLxAl3MRHhOoGYnTJMHg1OM0k8axPDseqQTKSwFqSYoz5MFJ0RMWoDoVNpqlDkJJgJopDrGS6zrQHEOkKVZGFCS69mmU55kaVQ1mOg5jrIN5cQcAggGjhFZFuH%200Vjm4rIJSILjxQwUVuOmoGjFmoTxVlcXxlwdycQm6SFWV-BJQw5WpUVISKNcDXZQgURocgIHtaIFrVaOGB4OG3FGbQoXmUlhYgP1oQTZ5I0OT5PVNc%20U2vkFXnzXEFLVcmK27g55mZkOfrFTwwbHbNpmugdcI3FlzU1dmF3MKNFoIkVxbJhdFSjWB44gKOTARPasF-cIQ6RsDMbHWDwYmPhsHDjcN23NcDA3QjcMw4jz4qWd8j2hGMjA3OomPKj7Uo7S6Mkx6lOPKdNZU0pJNgYzr6WjykMUnTtwM6j5XZTVA23TCTToSxQE1fw3CVchZOczCbPkSTYIZktt3CzdiL7DApCUHK8AQBi2J4oSJI4XTSGW7FgtiyL-6iylrPk1EdJWmDsH0rGbsKzmDZjlExZQTNrjlpwPY1pAfZOa2YA9mWsilgOHCMTRMjUT42V8KcHip5nf7Z3a8ior7Bcl-hahCVySkuIXcZOsZRVl43DdUDMZdCexld7jXKfl0hdfkbXGcIvgcksWocOj3DaRO8gM-pMIVCz1n5dd9nXDccPTG8-PDO%20MPcO75Pp1dYfp9tRvTDvsPVcD1fQ-%20IiD9FXw6R7SW0RxE-1rL08KDpGalQf0YUOqZDalHUIiMy4gURnwa40Da5eChJjZBXBrgFzQUrbAVo2YFwAdLJ4ODlS0VrgQscr9sCu0%20kg6hlCoh20wQw4W-hsyMJYP4eQxCuCLz0NLAWICOGMlYTeU4hAmqaU0F-WufCeHyFkXgmRx0laUBvBg4enU2poBSDBVMoZwwFmFnFTK2Y7gFRcGY4WZjHoWOmMLQmngjHmVauAm8Ws2pSJKBYJAWgkCOTiAASXcAgzGRAoFw38RQMho44FoMQRaUq9sbCOzsrQL4L0KBFQcck8GvhhpcHWKNMY8hxHKjEaOBIwCQAABM6AADMxAAFcAA2uIGDNLoNU2Y81Eg4TGBUsRz5KlMg4c2MIEQ2ohB0VI2pDSWltI6V0oQTJYCsApGhaZkQhJdUFojNGtJEakN%20m4AGyYt6-SKqc%200W8LS3HfsM3mNFJHLzmisuIlxHj3P5t4S2Wo3iLFNCsYU7xnQyilMCBUQZEl3MVvc2qHBbLpFsjcuR-1prCyGi8kKG1SYr3aivIavxbH4TuDjYY5hr4IQJqjWiUAw4R1rL2GOMA45VjrEnJ8y9FBF2yjdUlXK5bJgksqPJ2EU5uCePVA%204r5C5wldKihmcoJkt%20kmASiEpJBjBsjMGCgUwSCAvpa4z4DwznXF0UUmxBCQCMOEfqhAsBIEtcQPAF4bAuubGCR8YE7b6QmmS2mxqBU4xpuzK2iFfwkyCaRMc7ty7VzeVEn1NJcKw25X7cwbMDJrldkNCsFYqyRwTlWFl8d6UDlzIFBk-B6R4OQOHAt1ZGXdlLWy0sjEOVAA)

Comment: Are you doing homework? Ok... first suggestion, post your circuit and explain it.

Comment: Tip: put all the info in the question and delete the comments. That way all the info is in one place. Format the links properly using the link button. It's still not clear what problem you're trying to solve. Are the two pots for redundancy or what?

Comment: So, if one signal is 6.000 volts, the other signal should be 4.000 volts yes? What does 10% mean here in terms of go/no-go testing? What testing limits are on the cusp of passing/failing?

Comment: This seems very complicated. I think it would be better to perform all the signal screening digitally. Feed the output of both pots to micro-controller ADC inputs and let the micro sort it all out digitally.
Otherwise you need some kind of moving window comparator.

Comment: @Andyaka There's one signal that's going to go from 0V to 5V, and another that's inverted. The inverted goes from 10V to 5V. The issue is the actual Differential Amplifier part. I don't know how I can check for the deviation of >10% and send a signal out of that.

Comment: Since this seems to be too complex, I am most likely going to simply do it with a Micro-Controller, like @mkeith pointed out.

Comment: You still need to define what 10% means; does it mean 10% of 6.000 volt or, does it mean 10% of 4.000 volts. Or does it mean something else. You won't get far until you decide what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The hard way: make an analog path that does the following:

- normalize each pot for span and offset. Let's assume that's done mechanically, when the sensor is assembled.
- Add the normalized signals to each other. Their voltage sum should equal the reference voltage. The sum should not vary.
- use a pair of comparators that trip at -10% and +10% of reference.
- "OR" the two comparators together to make a composite compare signal (easy with LM339 which has open-collector output)

The mechanical arrangement simplifies the problem considerably. The two pots have opposite polarity, so the sum of the two should be a constant, the reference voltage. So we do the sum and compare to the reference using a *window detector*. In window = ok, out of window = fail.

Here's a circuit to do that ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgwMaQnsVwa3MIRDERESvCjQkABQYATAIYAbELID2AFzYBzHn3AYRTQkONQobAEo8wKPLUcsH4EVSo0qYD5ZgI2AA8eFGEQExoIYlo3EGsGADMGACcGADsAYwYAHQBnADUNFS0lXRzcgAp81ISASjYAd1jWfjxveyslEDbwV2FvV2iwJBYkH3g4WmhSUkk4GhniJDGJyEa3AcdOcVc1ptwhYn4DkBQEd3WTsCOQbGxxG7Xg0xEaMYR%20GkduFG55ZRUeQAyulchpknkKgBbJQASzS9WeCHIdyGS1uNE%20pz%20ilUwNB4Mh8IAbiktIp6k0ephWlQTmsutTzhtTsyhiNhshVlNFnNIAsZssufB1rx%20GY7K4JXsjCIzuILPT1ttWeJCFR5VYqXT%20bLbrqZdg8IdjsbbvctbczXcRHw6Ra1l4IDbaGFIq8whA8HlhnlRj7VpA8jRpoKJghOKwMMGZPy3sQ8IQwNgvMbvblxlIg7k0AHA1IwHlHZBnRaFh7XmJwN0fQg-b6M4G8ghoAsEAgnUa8MmvigY7zw5HOHms3lc4385NC7kZe7Xa8JXPZ26qzRF1W1slaIu3RLsB9LDQMHB1mvuHOz7QNzZt9x95892g-LQqEhfP42Fuaea5RhPpMqGISAgM3U4-xfDVwIjfgNQmT8wP4D5HG-dVHEA4CTyab8kIQigOkNMtJm-LwPEuMsejtJxSP2J8vjpWjDAI15DEougYMuBjjifF0mLw-hsPwsiHlNE1LUvcsKFcCSnloCNJOiBA8HIBBDB%20bgAGENChAAHJRUjyAB5ABrIJZNfL5uh8Cg5KEEQAAlYV0AALPIGic9JIWqRJ60gABSWo8gAHk86dsm0vJ8hQALcmCyovISPIwoDfy8ng34NWZE5NVgkUAFlJO%20Ktzk8DdThkdYejAQRum8CxQPS3pHCuXZTjgpp%20kalkVRlDqVUqurLl1ewmqGx51ga4a9UmlBxq8VU9U1Gb9G-F0VqfUj7mQ8CSNa74AKsTbcOg3a%20L8cbwNQyVHEutZDqNUS52uGDLTCBrqTm0CcMOnCl3NWc9wPL6DxlIHENcQ61mEMHvjCH6JX4BREiUABXYomBURRq3fWB2CaOHuB%2069OG4MVcNe35qz5aQkAASTSUlknJBR1G0UVDCqkn2YGppSbQZwuYuHnDG-Xm8DQtn%20LFq7TilmVSYlUmejlyaLJca7uGVqUSem2XRR15xJpu0zBH4yYVNN%20hbJAKpQvCgooryAB6MdTIQaIvHIYQPU8WIqhqP1kui52c1d5TOWERwI2%20X34sSu2fBS3Jg5m4J2yQQQkEIFBLYsq2ADEAEEaYAGTyYuAFEABE2CAA)):

[image]

The math is very simple. Compare the sum of the two vs. Vref +/- 10% with the window comparator. [We also use a small trick with average](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/passive-averager.html) and scale the comparator trip points to make the design less complex, saving an op-amp in the process.

That is:

- as designed: (Vref-10%)**/2** < (V1 + V2)**/2** < (Vref+10%)**/2** = 'OK'
- is equivalent to: (Vref-10%) < (V1 + V2) < (Vref + 10%) = 'OK'

The mechanical limitation you've specified of 0-5V and 10-5V doesn't matter, this circuit works for the entire 0-10 / 10-0V range. 2-7V and 8-3V works equally well, depending on where the sensor indexes.

Limitations: completely ignorant of actuator angle or pot linearity. Requires manual calibration. But if you’re thinking about, say, a Bookout v. Toyota case, this purely analog approach might be what you want to do.

More about *Bookout*: [http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/ece649/lectures/08_toyota_ua.pdf](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Ekoopman/ece649/lectures/08_toyota_ua.pdf)

The easy way: use a microcontroller with two ADC inputs. Calibrate the span, offset, and linearity of each pot as they actuate through their travel. Normalize the transfer functions to your chosen data range. Then, do the  comparison and thresholding math.

Limitation: functional safety of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUlAGO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with R1 not equal to R2.The reason why R1 is not equal to R2 is to introduce the 10% difference.This circuit is just a differential to single ended converter but now that R1 is not equal to R2 VsA must be much greater than VsB (not just 0.1V up)in order for Vout to become logic 1 and you can adjust how greater VsA must be than VsB in order for logic 1 output by changing the value of the resistors R1 and R2.